# Variable is declared but its value is never read JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, input, slider

my goal is to get the Close button in this modal to leave the inputs as they are when the Save button has been pressed before.  It already Saves the values and resets them when I click the Cancel button but my variable "saved" is declared and even when I use it in the functions it shows me this error and doesnt do what I want.

```
import {
    getInput, setInput
} from '../../service/data'

let close = document.getElementById('advsettings_close');
let cancel = document.getElementById('advsettings_cancel');
let save = document.getElementById('advsettings_save');
const settingsForm = document.getElementById('advsettings_form');
const settingsSliders = settingsForm.querySelectorAll('input');
var saved = false;


cancel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cancelSettings();
});

save.addEventListener('click', function() {
    saveSettings();
});

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    closeSettings();
});

settingsForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

function cancelSettings(){
    settingsSliders.forEach(function(input) {
         input.value = 5;
        console.log('Values canceled and reset');

    });
    saved = false;
}

function saveSettings(){
    settingsSliders.forEach(function(input) {
        if (input.type === 'range') {
            setInput(input.name, input.value);
            console.log('Save Value of ' + input.name + ':', input.value);
        }
    });
    saved = true;
}

function closeSettings(){
    settingsSliders.forEach(function(input) {
        if (saved = true){
            input.value = setInput(input.name, getInput(input.value));
        } else if(saved = false) {
            input.value = 5;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the if confition:

```
function closeSettings(){
  settingsSliders.forEach(function(input) {
    if (saved == true){
        input.value = setInput(input.name, getInput(input.value));
    } else if(saved == false) {
        input.value = 5;
    }
 }
```

Also, it is better to directly evaluate conditions as booleans:

```
function closeSettings(){
  settingsSliders.forEach(function(input) {
    if (saved){
        input.value = setInput(input.name, getInput(input.value));
    } else{
        input.value = 5;
    }
 }
```